# How to force JMeter to assign different ports to different threads?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I want to assign to each different threads creted by JMeter a different port from which they send their requests. For instance, if I have 10 threads, then I'd like that each of them uses a different port, e.g in the range 4444 to 4453.

Answer (score 0):

You can have dynamic port using functions and [${__threadNum}](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) in [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)'s Port Number field, use:

```
${__groovy(${__threadNum}+4444,)}
```

> The thread number function simply returns the number of the thread currently being executed.

Comment: And where shoul I insert it? Sorry I'm new at using JMeter
Know that I'm using a CoAP plugin to send CoAP requests

Comment: I just edited the answer ahaha. Anyway I'm using a CoAP plugin to handle CoAP requests and there is no such a field

Comment: Thanks. But I'm using this plugin https://github.com/starrlingo/jmeter-iot-lib. As you can see the creator provides just the .jar file. I can't update nothing. Unfortunatelly this is the only plugin that works (I tried four before this and they all gave me different errors)

Comment: @Luigi2405 try adding port inside URL field

Comment: I just can add the destination port, but I need to control the source port.

Comment: Is there a way to schedule requests like I want, without using the GUI?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Config Element -> Random Variable option and set Per Thread option to "True"(this will assign one random value to each thread/virtual user). 
If you want to make it different every iteration and user then form string by concatenating two/multiple random variables.
I hope this will help you.. :)